# setup multiple tsd on hbase cluster

Tags: hadoop, hbase, time-series, cluster-computing, opentsdb

What all configurations are need to be done in setting up multiple opentsdb instance on my HBase Cluster ? I would like to set up some instance for write and some for read only.

Have found this link

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/opentsdb/multiple$20tsd/opentsdb/NiTKnsmm7NI/O7mPzWwwshYJ

but I'm confused in whether all the instance need to point to my Single Master node on which HMaster daemon is running ?
What to set these properties in different instances ?

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/opentsdb/multiple$20tsd/opentsdb/nZ59_xMaRvo/_ZWzCdj0FU8J

```
tsd.storage.hbase.data_table
tsd.storage.hbase.uid_table
tsd.storage.hbase.zk_basedir
tsd.storage.hbase.zk_quorum
tsd.mode = rw /ro ?
```

Answer (score 1):

To setup multiple OpenTSDB instance you need to point them all to your Hbase Master.

1. **tsd.storage.hbase.data_table** - The table in HBase you are using to store TSDB data. Generally its "tsdb".
2. **tsd.storage.hbase.uid_table** - The table in HBase you are using to store TSDB metric uid data. Generally its "tsdb-uid".
3. **tsd.storage.hbase.zk_basedir** - The hbase znode in zookeeper. Defined by property zookeeper.znode.parent in hbase-site.xml. By default its /hbase
4. **tsd.storage.hbase.zk_quorun** - List of all servers in your zookeeper quorum.
5. **tsd.mode** - This is set as 'ro' (readonly) in all the read instances of TSDB. By default its 'rw' (read-write).